# Firebase: Retrieving data sorted by child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My structure is like following

```
- Posts
   - keu23jndf
     - dateTime:"2376464"
     - name:"abc"
   - key34njf
     - dateTime:"4333434"
     - name:"xyz"
```

Now, I want to retrieve sorted data by dateTime in descending order.

Thanks

Comment: With which code language are you working? Do you want to sort them from newest to oldest or reverse? What kind of timestamp is that?

Comment: I am using Android and I want to sort them newest to oldest. Timestamp is like                                                                                                        Long timestamp= System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

Answer (score 2):

Ok so first of all I would suggest you to not use a client sided timestamp but instead use the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. In most cases this is going to be the better setup. If you know what you are doing and you want it exactly like that, forget this and just read on.

The problem if you want to sort from newest to oldest is that Firebase does (as far as I know) not support this.

A workaround would be to use the negative value of the Firebase `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

This is how I do it. **It may not be the perfect or right way, but it does work**

```
private void prepareUpload() {
    //mDatabase is a reference to the root of the Firebase Database
    final DatabaseReference timestampReference = mDatabase.child("timestamp");
    final String timestampKey = timestampReference.push().getKey();
    timestampReference.child(timestampKey).setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    timestampReference.child(timestampKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                Long timestamp = 0 - Long.parseLong(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                upload(/*Starting upload with new timestamp here (this is just a dummy method)*/);
                timestampReference.child(timestampKey).removeValue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Now you have to set your Firebase Database rules as follows:

```
"Posts": {
  ".indexOn" : "date",
  ...
}
```

Finally you just have to query your `'Posts'` somehow like this:

```
mDatabase.child("Posts").orderByChild("dateTime").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Do stuff with your data
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want addValueEventListener

Comment: Then just change the `ChildEvent` listener to a `ValueEvent` listener.

Comment: That's not a really helpful comment. You should try to specify errors and update your question if you tried out my answer.

Comment: @hotrod Thanks for all your recent help to Firebase users! Keep in mind that there are valid reasons for using the client-side timestamp (for example: if you want to record when something happened according to the user's time). From OPs description I'm not sure server-side timestamps are better or even relevant at all.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that is a good point. I edited my answer to reflect your comment.